# Motors latching on - diy RC car

Tags: motor, automotive, remote-control, motordriver

I am building a little diy RC car/robot from salvaged parts. Here is what I am using:

- Chassis and motors from an old RC car. They are normal hobby/toy  motors.
- MX1919 motor driver from something (pretty hard to find info on this IC, I am going to add the pin out information once I figure out how to make it less that 2MB).
- 5v regulator for the receiver (because I plan on powering it with a 2s LiPo).
- Receiver/transmitter from a cheap Walmart RC car (it says it is 2.4GHz).

The problem right now is that the motors are staying on when I move the sticks in the controller. They spin in the correct direction, etc., but they stay on when the sticks are in neutral position. I’ll include pictures of the circuit.
Any suggestions for how to go about fixing this would be awesome! Please tell me if I need to add more information. [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a large enough deadzone on the controls.

Comment: True, but the thing that is confusing is that the car I got worked, then I took it apart to get the receiver. I’m not sure what changed with the receiver between me driving the car around and then putting the receiver in this (other than other things being connected to it.

Comment: One thing I thought could be the problem is that the outputs from the receiver that I hooked up to the motor driver were meant to drive the motors directly, not control a motor driver. I’m not sure how that would cause problems though.

Comment: Is it possible the inputs to the motor driver are floating when the sticks are dropped?

Comment: Just tested that, it looks like the receiver is still sending a signal to the inputs when the sticks are not moved.